# Filter between max date and -7 days from max date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

1. r_table

[image]

```
select max(r_date) 
from r_table
where r_type ='Ground'
```

Result -->10 Jan 2020

2. c_table

```
select c_id  
from c_table  
where
c_date betweem [max("r_date") -7 days] and [max(r_date)]
```

that is, c_date should be filtered between "3rd Jan" and "10 Jan"

My try:

```
WITH 
     max   
     AS (SELECT MAX(r_date) AS max_r_date FROM r_table)

select c_id  
from c_table  
where
c_date between (SELECT max_r_date FROM max) and (select max-7 from ??) --unable to complete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
WITH cte_max AS (SELECT MAX(r_date) AS max_r_date FROM r_table where r_type ='Ground')

select c_id  
from c_table join cte_max on 
c_date>=dateadd('day',-7,max_r_date) and c_date<=max_r_date
```

Comment: @user14263992, what is the error? I've updated the answer you can check

Comment: Thanks for updating. 
Error: Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", integer, text) does not exist

Comment: @user14263992, updated the answer again - you can check

Comment: Thanks. I tried 'day' just now. Looks like r_date field is not defined as a date column. Trying to insert to_date()